# Eclipse autocomplete change variable names

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

just a dumb question but its hard to search because there are so many topics about eclipse auto complete and its hard to find something matching to my problem.

so there problem is:

If i write :
"MyClass MyVarName" and then hit space, (to add the " = new MyClass()")
Eclipse automatically adds : "MyClass MyVarName_**MyClass**  " or something like that to the variable-name..... (just without underscore.... stackoverflow just wont to mark as bold else...)

That is really annoying, and because i imported the eclipse configuration of a co-worker... I really don't know how to disable....

thanks in advance

//EDIT:

It seems to be the same effect as i type "MyC" and then press space, it also completes the "MyClass" and not add just the space... its like hitting enter. but i dont want to automplete on space...

i also didn't found a custom key option on space or else.... :(

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 9):

In Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist:

check the box at "Disable Insertion triggers except 'Enter' ".

I've found all other answers to also disable the auto-suggestion features of Eclipse, which are rather useful in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced: In the top list box, uncheck "Java Non-Type Proposals", "Java Proposals" and "Java Proposals (Task-Focused)".

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a way to solve it decently.

So, just, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you might have the Control key pressed without knowing it. Happens sometimes on laptops with Fn key that Fn+Ctrl kind of "locks" the Ctrl. I conclude this because Eclipse auto-complete feature should not work on pressing Spacebar only. Normally you should get the effect you describe only by pressing CTRL+Spacebar. Thus, try pressing Fn+Ctrl to unlock the "pressed down" Ctrl key and then you should be fine.

Comment: Not the case, to me it's never relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Look into

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style

There you can see **Conventions for variable names**. Make sure all prefixes and suffixes are empty. Also check in

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist

Answer (score 0):

In Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist, there is the option "Auto Activation". If you have it checked, it will activate even if you don't press ctrl and you'll see that behaviour. Uncheck it and you'll only get content assist when you use ctrl+space.

S!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, and what I do, is similar to GreenEyed's approach but instead of disabling auto activation put it to a reasonable value for the delay, like 3000 (3 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I had plain Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and installed the Spring plugin to try it out.  I didn't like it and didn't use it so I uninstalled it.  After uninstalling, it still had the setting that you describe.  So annoying!

After search for hours, I *finally* found out how to disable it.

Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist
Set *Auto activation triggers for Java* to: `.`

That's all that's necessary.

If you want to restore other Eclipse defaults regarding content assist:

Set *Auto activation delay* to 200.

I had previously disabled Java Proposals, Java Proposals (Task-Focused), and Java Type Proposals, as others recommended, but these should actually stay checked, so I re-enabled them.