# How do I disable automatic variable name generation in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

environment : Eclipse Photon 4.8.0

When I declare a variable in Eclipse, Intelisense always automatically creates my variable name.

## Example)

What I wanted to do

`String str;`

If variable names are automatically created

`String string;`

I want to solve this problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Windows > Prefereces > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Auto activation triggers for Java

Comment: @John Joe Thank you for your comment.
But I want to automatically create names for types, methods, etc., except that variable names are automatically created.
The value below is the value currently set for my Auto activation triggers for Java element.
`.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589590/eclipse-autocomplete-change-variable-names

Comment: @John Joe Thank you very much!

Comment: Did the link helped ?

Comment: @John Joe It's not fundamentally resolved, but it's close to what I want.